# Swift - Text Input in UIAlertView

Tags: swift, uialertview

I have two errors here. I'm trying to get a UIAlertView that comes up when the button is pressed. From there, I want the user to input a new number (Double) and then have it update the variable timeWorkedGoal as well as the timeWorkedGoalNumber label.

I'm getting the error "Use of unresolved identifier 'UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad'" as well as the error "Reference to property 'timeWorkedGoalNumber' in closure requires explicit 'self'. to make capture semantics explicit." Does anybody know how my syntax is off? Thanks!

```
var timeWorkedGoal = 1.1


@IBOutlet weak var timeWorkedGoalNumber: UILabel!


    @IBAction func resetTimeWorkedGoalButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    var timeWorkedAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Time Worked", message: "Your current work time goal is \(timeWorkedGoal) hours – Enter your new goal.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    timeWorkedAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
        (textField) in
    }

    timeWorkedAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .Default, handler: {
        (action) in

        let textF = timeWorkedAlert.textFields![0] as UITextField
        print(textF)

        textF.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;

        timeWorkedGoal = (Double("\(textF)"))!

        print(timeWorkedGoal)
        timeWorkedGoalNumber.text = "\(textF)"

    }))

    timeWorkedAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: {
        (action) in

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


    }))

    self.presentViewController(timeWorkedAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Error "Use of unresolved identifier 'UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad'"

Use `textF.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad`

> Reference to property 'timeWorkedGoalNumber' in closure requires
>   explicit 'self'

Explains itself. Instead of just using
 `timeWorkedGoalNumber` use `self.timeWorkedGoalNumber`

also you need to update `timeWorkedGoal = (Double("\(textF)"))!` to `self.timeWorkedGoal = (Double("\(textF)"))!`

**EDIT:**
`textF` is a type of `UITextField` so cannot be directly cast to a `Double`. Insted you can use `textF.text` that will return you a `String`. So you will have something like this `Double("\(textF.text)")`

Comment: thanks for the solution. I'm still getting the following error.

http://i.imgur.com/CfanKyi.png

Answer (score 0):

First Question:

```
textF.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad
```

Second Question:

Add

```
self.timeWorkedGoal = (Double("\(textF)"))!
```

instead it was previously

```
timeWorkedGoal = (Double("\(textF)"))!
```